# How to setTitle, containing words and variable?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to `setBadge` and `setTitle` like

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(badgeText)});
chrome.browserAction.setTitle({text: "The number "+currentDomain+ "is "+ String(badgeText)});
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: '#1d2554' });
```

But in the title remains the title, which is set in the manifest, and the badge color becomes default blue. As error i'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of browserAction.setTitle(object details, optional function callback): 
Error at parameter 'details': Unexpected property: 'text'.
```

What i'm doing wrong? What is the correct syntax for this?

PS: Existence of `default_title` in the manifest doesn't play a role - if it isn't set, the title shows the name from manifest, but not the title i set in background.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be title instead of text, like:
`chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title: "The number "+currentDomain+ "is "+ String(badgeText)});`
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setTitle

Also you might want to make it more readable by using template literals, so it would be:
{title: `The number ${currentDomain} is ${String(badgeText)}`}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals